# How can I split the screens of two vertical monitors like this?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, multiple-monitors, split-window

[image: image of setup i want to achieve]

I am running Windows 10 64 bit.  I have two vertical monitors in Extended display mode that will always display Google Chrome (As shown above). Monitor 1 will always show one tab of Google Chrome and so will the other three.  Is there a way to do this?

Also, preferably, the screens should always remain this way or snap to this format when Google Chrome is opened.

Comment: Do you just need assistance with getting the chrome windows on those screens or the actual setup as well?

Comment: @Seth just getting the chrome windows on the screens

Comment: @Chenmunka Why not add an answer that describes how to do this? Does it work only for Chrome, or for other apps, also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way of tiling tabs like this on your monitors.  However, not using Chrome.

If you use the [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/) browser, tabs can be [tiled](https://vivaldi.com/features/) in a grid pattern.

To get the large left panel that you have in your diagram, you would need the Vivaldi [Panel](https://vivalditips.com/efficiency/panels/en) feature.

This pattern can be [saved](https://vivalditips.com/efficiency/tab-tiling/en) so that it can be recreated when required.

[image: Vivaldi screenshot]